# How to find xpath of a text if it is a substring of a string in the same dom

Tags: xpath, nodes, ambiguous

```
<div>
    <p>BBC Radio 1</p>
    <p>BBC Radio 1Xtra</p>
</div>
```

I want to locate the first element(containing text BBC Radio 1) using the xpath which contains tthe paragraph text. Something like : `"//div[contains(text(),'BBC Radio 1')]".`

However this xpath is pointing to both the `<p>` nodes. Is there a way to point to the first `<p>` node only using the node text in this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

You can limit result of your XPath by using index 1 :

```
(your_initial_xpath_here)[1]

(//p[contains(text(),'BBC Radio 1')])[1]
```

Comment: That can be used but it will  not be prefect if i don't know the position of these ambiguous nodes